# constexpr const char* in header file

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a reason to not use "constexpr const char*" in header file?

The argument from a colleague is that every translation unit including this header file would have a copy.

My understanding was that since its compile-time constant, no memory is allocated and acts more like a "#define" macro with respect to memory usage.
Here is the source,

TestConstExpr.h

```
  #include <string.h>
  namespace TestConstExpr
  {
    constexpr const char* TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
    constexpr const int TIME_FORMAT_SIZE = strlen(TIME_FORMAT) + 1;

    class TestClass
    {
        char arr[TIME_FORMAT_SIZE];
    }
  }
```

Comment: `char const *`? certainly not, a reference to constant array or a getter function - way to go. Also your understanding is not correct. Memory is allocated in exactly the same manner as if it was in source file.

Comment: I suggest you try it out with bloaty mcbloatface - compile that headers into multiple TUs, then link them together with -O2 and see if the string is duplicated or not!

Answer (score 4):

> The argument from a colleague is that every translation unit including this header file would have a copy.

You're colleague is technically correct. But it doesn't matter, since the redundant copies are thrown away when the units are linked together.

Although, I've seen comments about this not being necessarily the case on some non-standard-conforming systems when dynamic linking is involved.

---

> ```
> constexpr const char* TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
> .... sizeof(TIME_FORMAT)
> ```

This doesn't do what you probably think it does. It gives you the size of the pointer, not the size of the pointed string.

> ```
> constexpr const int TIME_FORMAT_SIZE = strlen(TIME_FORMAT) + 1;
> ```

Your attempted fix also doesn't work, because `strlen` is not a constant expression.

You can fix the problems by using a reference to the string literal:

```
static constexpr auto& TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
constexpr const int TIME_FORMAT_SIZE = sizeof(TIME_FORMAT);
```

Comment: Using string literal throws multiple definition error if that header is included in more than one cpp file.
multiple definition of `TestConstExpr::TIME_FORMAT'

Comment: @NaveenGara it appears that for some reason the variable has external linkage by default despite being constexpr. You can use `static` keyword to use internal linkage explicitly.